# How do I initialize a one-dimensional array of two-dimensional elements in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to initialize an array that has X two-dimensional elements. For example, if X = 3, I want it to be [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0]]. I know that [0]*3 gives [0, 0, 0], but how do I do this for two-dimensional elements?

Comment: Most of the time in Python, if you are thinking in terms of "initializing" a container to a bunch of 0s, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Well I'm practicing for Google Code Jam and I have to read in a stream of numbers for example 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2 and turn it into [[2,3], [1,4], [5,2]]. What else would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest appending the numbers to empty lists as they are received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
m = [[0] * 2 for _ in xrange(3)]
```

In the above code, think of the `3` as the number of rows in a matrix, and the `2` as the number of columns. The `0` is the value you want to use for initializing the elements. Bear in mind this: if you're using Python 3, use `range` instead of `xrange`.

For a more general solution, use this function:

```
def create_matrix(m, n, initial=0):
    return [[initial] * n for _ in xrange(m)]
```

For the particular case of the question:

```
m = create_matrix(3, 2)
print m
> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Alternatively, and if you don't mind using `numpy`, you can use the `numpy.zeros()` function as shown in Mellkor's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is useful for such. Say,

```
x=4

numpy.zeros((x,x))
```

will give you:

> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's `[[0,0],]*3`

Comment: The way it works is it adds the stuff inside the list as a list to itself multiple times, essentially being [[0,0],]+[[0,0],]+[[0,0],]

Comment: This makes a list containing three references to the same list, so it's not the same as `[[0,0],]+[[0,0],]+[[0,0],]`.  Try changing one of the elements, and you'll see all three sublists change.

Comment: This solution is broken. It creates 3 copies of the _same_ list of two elements, when you try to modify one, _all_ the others will get modified too.

Answer (score 0):

Using the construct

`[[0,0]]*3`

works just fine and returns the following:

`[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]`